# find key name by value in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I need to get key name by value.

Json Object:

```
 {
   None : 0,
   Public : 82001,
   Unclassified : 82002,
   Restricted : 82003,
   Confidential : 82004,
   Secret : 82005,
   TopSecret : 82006,
   Private : 82007
}
```

`example : I have value 82004 , I want to get key name (Confidential);`

Comment: Can you give example?...

Comment: you can try this                      
   ` $.each(data, function (key, value) {
     if (value === 0) {
      alert(key);
    }

});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {
    None: 0,
    Public: 82001,
    Unclassified: 82002,
    Restricted: 82003,
    Confidential: 82004,
    Secret: 82005,
    TopSecret: 82006,
    Private: 82007
}


$.each(data, function (inx, val) {
    if (val === 82004) {
        console.log(inx)
    }

})
```

Try this one

Comment: thanks, its working.

Comment: grad it helped happy coding